# $a_n$ diverge $\nRightarrow a^2_n - a_n + 1$ diverges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> Let $a_n$ be divergent sequence. Then a sequence $a^2_n - a_n + 1$ diverges.

I have difficulties with finding out a counterexample. Could you help me?

Comment: A hint would be: look at the function $f(x) = x^2 - x + 1$, find to numbers $x_1\ne x_2$ with $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$. Then consider the sequence that alternates between $x_1$ and $x_2$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Hint**: take $a_n=1$ for $n$ odd and $a_n=0$ for $n$ even.

Comment: Thanks, it's an answer, not a hint :)